# jQuery only works in .html file and it doesn't work in .PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an HTML file with a simple jQuery highlight effect in it.

This works fine. But when i change the extension of the file from .html to .php and I upload it to my server, it just doesn't work.

by it doesn't work i mean it doesn't highlight the Div.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<style>
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hflip.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter"></div>
<form>
<input name="ajaxlink" type="button" id="ajaxlink" class="ajaxlink" />
</form>
<script>
$( '#ajaxlink' ).click(function() {
$( "#counter" ).effect( "highlight", "slow" );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

what am I doing wrong? why it works fine in an HTML file and it doesn't in a .PHP file?

Comment: What exactly happens when you change the extension to PHP and load it? Are you sure your server supports PHP?

Comment: you sure this is your code, as it is giving an Typeerror $(...).effect is not a function ?

Comment: @JonathonHenderson, nothing happens. when i click the button it doesn't highlight the Div as it should. and yes, my server supports PHP.

Comment: you're calling jquery 1.9.1 twice too

Comment: Why are you trying to load jQuery twice?  Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: @SKV, yes that is my code. What is not a function?

Comment: OMG, i was calling the jquery twice!!! i've removed the mini one and it started working in the PHP. I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this script and run your code.. :)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `<body>` (open tag). and twice inclusion of jquery

Answer (score 0):

just replace :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and remove the last script inclusion

Working fine with PHP file extension too..

Please check